# How can I securely gain programmatic access to supervisord via xmlrpc?

Tags: python, linux, security, xml-rpc, supervisord

I need to be able to manage the supervisord setup programmatically. Furthermore, not any user on the system should be able to to gain access to configuration of supervisord. For this reason, communication needs to be secured somehow.

I know that supervisord offers programmatic access in the form of XML-RPC. I read the documentation and attempted to work with it in several ways, but I keep running into problems.

1. On the [Introduction page](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html#supervisor-components), the documentation recommends running an HTTP server for the XML-RPC interface and using the Python standard library [xmlrpclib](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/xmlrpclib.html) to communicate with it. There are two problems here:

   - The `inet_http_server` directive for supervisord.conf only includes username, password, and port as settings. There is no option to encrypt the connection.
   - xmlrpclib doesn't even support usernames and passwords. When I use the syntax `username:password@host:port`, I get `IOError: unsupported XML-RPC protocol`. As you can see in the example on the documentation page, no authentication occurs.
2. Since UNIX sockets are secure, I figured that connecting to the `[unix_http_server]` with xmlrpclib would be a good idea. Still, I don't know how authentication would work, and furthermore, xmlrpclib only supports network HTTP/HTTPS servers.
3. Another page in the documentation mentions a `supervisor.rpcinterface` module. I have no access to such a thing in Python, though. To glean more information as to why that is, I re-installed supervisord with Pip. `sudo pip install --upgrade supervisor`. In the pip output, I see the line `Skipping installation of /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/supervisor/__init__.py (namespace package)`. I don't know why it would skip installation of the namespace package.

How am I supposed to communicate programmatically and securely with supervisord?

Answer (score 1):

Supervisor supports options to set permissions on the Unix domain socket.

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#unix-http-server-section-example

I don't know the details but you should be able to call the xmlrpc interface over UNIX domain socket the same way that supervisorctl.py does.  It's calling options.getServerProxy() to get an xmlrpclib.ServerProxy object.

https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/supervisorctl.py#L188